# How to retrieve metadata from record triggered flow with custom error message?

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment, metadata, error-messages

Currently I trying to retrieve metadata form Record-Triggered Flow with new custom error message component

[image]

But when I deploy to another sandbox org, I received this message

[image]

When I check the xml, I see that it refers to the name of the component and the message configuration does not appear in the xml, it seems that it is an independent component.

```
<defaultConnector>
            <targetReference>Error_message</targetReference>
</defaultConnector>
<defaultConnectorLabel>At least one is unchecked</defaultConnectorLabel>
```

Will anyone know what metadata I should obtain so that I can deploy the complete flow with the custom error message?

Answer (score 1):

After deploying by Change sets, I see that XML generated has `<apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>`

In VSCode automatically set apiVersion 58.0, changing to newer version and retrieve Flow metadata normally, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Can you share metadata for Custom Error.
I have api version as 59.0 only.

Update:
I figured out the solution. Please use below command to retrieve your flow metadata. It is important to mention api version at the end of command then only you will be able to retrieve the complete metadata.

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:Your_Flow_Name -a 59.0

If anyone want custom error metadata then below is the syntax,

```
<customErrors>
        <name>Show_relation_error</name>
        <label>Show relation error</label>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>503</locationY>
        <customErrorMessages>
            <errorMessage>The error message</errorMessage>
            <fieldSelection>Field_Api_name_Where_it_will_show_error</fieldSelection>
            <isFieldError>true</isFieldError>
        </customErrorMessages>
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/204526)

Comment: @identigral Please remove delete flag as now I have provided answer that don't require clarification from the asker.